# coredump in CORBA::is_nil(obj)

Tags: c++, corba

I am getting coredump in CORBA method is_nil(obj).

When i tried checking whether the object passed in nil or not i am getting core dump

```
if (! ::CORBA::is_nil (obj))
{
  obj->_add_ref ();
}

return obj;
```

here is the dbx output of core dump:

```
=>[1] CORBA::Object::is_nil_i(0xff55cef4, 0xff55cef4, 0x989681, 0x0, 0xfd434760,     0x655db0), at 0xfe9dfbbc 
[2] CORBA::is_nil(0xff55cef4, 0x996ad8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xfc0fb98c), at 0x199838
```

How to get rid of this one. How to handle this in code. 
I cannot make changes in the c code, because it is CORBA generated.

Comment: is obj declared as type CORBA::Object or derived objects?

Comment: ÒS and ORB might be of interest, too.

Comment: Sounds like invalid memory, maybe the memory is alreadt deleted because of reference count problems. Try to run with valgrind.